# Array not getting saved in local storage

Tags: javascript, arrays, forms, object

I'm trying to save Form (non-validated) details and save them in localStorage in JAVASCRIPT, which I have done. But when I reload the browser and click submit the previous value which was supposed to save is not saved in the 'array' and the blank form is replaced. I know the array and the object (`var client_Array = [];var clientObj = {};`) gets initialized again when i load the browser, but isn't the Array supposed to keep a copy of the old details (say in index 0) and push the blank or new copy in index 1?. That doesn't seem to be happening now.
Also this code works only in chrome and not working in FF (not showing the details in the console when clicked in 'load' btn).
...please help. thanks in advance.

```
<head>
<style>
form {
    width:300px;
}
input {
    border:1px solid #FF9933;
    width:225px;
    height:24px;
    margin-bottom:7px;
}
textarea {
    border:1px solid #FF9933;
    width:225px;
    height:100px;
}
.fbtn {
    width:80px;
    margin-top:10px;
    float:right;
    text-align:center;
    color:#FF6600;
    font-weight:bold;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form>
  <table border="0">
    <tr>
      <td width="64">Name</td>
      <td width="8">:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="inp_name" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Email</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="inp_email" ></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Phone</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="inp_phone"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Address</td>
      <td>:</td>
      <td><textarea id="inp_address"></textarea>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" onClick="sendDet()" class="fbtn" value="Submit">
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="button" onClick="loadit()" class="fbtn" value="Load">
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="reset" class="fbtn"  value="reset">
</form>
<script>

var client_Array = [];
var clientObj = {};



function sendDet(){
var clientObj = {
 name : document.getElementById('inp_name').value,
  email : document.getElementById('inp_email').value,
   phone : document.getElementById('inp_phone').value,
    address : document.getElementById('inp_address').value
}

client_Array.push(clientObj)

localStorage.setItem("client", JSON.stringify(client_Array))


}

function loadit(){
var show = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("client")) 
console.log(show)
}


</script>
</body>
```

Comment: From what I understand what you want is not to overwrite the new values but to keep them in an array with old entries, no?

Comment: You can use garlic.js for data persist.

Comment: @Darth Batu ..yes...

Answer (score 0):

Instead of client_Array.push, you should use client_Array.unshift. push adds the item at the end of the array, while unshift adds it as the 1st element (which is index 0 BTW, not 1)